# Why does this directive not work in internet explorer 8.It is failing without any errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

This is a angular js directive that pops up with a confirm
 The code is pretty much working in all the other browsers.How can i fix this to work in IE 8.I dont  know how to fix this in internet explorer 8.

```
AccountsApp.directive('confirm', function ($document, $parse) {
var definition = {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var message = attrs.confirm || "Are you sure?";
        var popup = angular.element('<div class="message tooltip tracking" style="z-index: 99; position: absolute; opacity: 1;"><div class="with-small-padding align-center" style="display: block;"><div class="mid-margin-bottom">' + message + '</div><cancel style="cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;" class="button mid-margin-right" type="button">Cancel</cancel><confirm class="button blue-gradient glossy" style="cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;" type="button">Confirm</confirm></div><span class="block-arrow bottom"><span></span></span></div>');
        var okCallback = $parse(attrs.okClick);
        var cancelCallback = $parse(attrs.cancelClick);

        $document.bind('click', function () {
            if (event.target == element[0]) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                return;
            }
            popup.remove();
        });

        element.bind('click', function () {
            var btnConfirm = popup.find('confirm');
            var btnCancel = popup.find("cancel");
            var body = angular.element($document[0].body);
            body.append(popup);

            var pHeight = popup.prop('offsetHeight');
            var pWidth = popup.prop('offsetWidth');

            var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();

            popup.css({
                top: (rect.top - pHeight - 12) + 'px',
                left: (rect.left - (pWidth - this.clientWidth) / 2) + 'px'
            });

            btnCancel.bind('click', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    cancelCallback(scope);
                    popup.remove();
                });
            });

            btnConfirm.bind('click', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    okCallback(scope);
                    popup.remove();
                });
            });

            scope.$apply();
        });
    }
};

return definition;
});
```

Here is how the directive gets used.Html code

Comment: can you show the html code as well ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PCB2D/58/

Comment: in the fiddle it is working but it is not working in Ie 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work also with FireFox and IE10. Firefox complains

- about double cursor declaration: `cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;`
- missing declaration for `event` in `if (event.target == element[0]) {`. Error `ReferenceError: event is not defined` is reported.

I deleted `cursor:hand;` at two places and changed

```
        $document.bind('click', function () {
            if (event.target == element[0]) {
```

to

```
    $document.bind('click', function (event) {
        if (event.target == element[0]) {
```

So FF and IE10 swallowed it and got the same response as with Chrome.

Switch IE10 to IE9 behaviour: the same response as with Chrome, FF

Switch IE10 to IE8 behaviour: doesn't work with v. 1.0.7

Switch IE10 to IE8 behaviour: using with v. 1.0.2: the same response as with Chrome, FF

Comment: I also found those mistakes except for the cursor hand. I am also using a custom tags in the directive , cancel and confirm that Ie 8 did not support .

Comment: but now for some reason the fix on angular is not working for my custom elements im using

Comment: I fixed it just removed the custom tags from my directive.

Answer (score 0):

Its working way better like this , found all my mistakes , thanks for the help Jurkovic

```
AccountsApp.directive('developrConfirm', function ($document, $parse) {
var definition = {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var message = attrs.developrConfirm || "Are you sure?";
        var popup = angular.element('<div class="message tooltip tracking" style="z-index: 99; position: absolute; opacity: 1;"></div>');


        var content = angular.element('<div class="with-small-padding align-center" style="display: block;"></div>');
        var lblmessage = angular.element('<div class="mid-margin-bottom">' + message + '</div>');
        var btnCancel = angular.element('<button class="button mid-margin-right" type="button">Cancel</button>');
        var btnConfirm = angular.element('<button class="button blue-gradient glossy" type="button">Confirm</button>');
        content.append(lblmessage);
        content.append(btnCancel);
        content.append(btnConfirm);
        var footer = angular.element('<span class="block-arrow bottom"><span></span></span>');
        popup.append(content);
        popup.append(footer);
        var okCallback = $parse(attrs.okClick);
        var cancelCallback = $parse(attrs.cancelClick);

        $document.bind('click', function (event) {
            if (event.target == element[0]) {
                alert('button clicked');
                //event.preventDefault();
            } else {
                alert('otherplace clicked');
                popup.remove();
            }
        });

        element.bind('click', function () {
            var body = angular.element($document[0].body);
            body.append(popup);

            var pHeight = popup.prop('offsetHeight');
            var pWidth = popup.prop('offsetWidth');

            var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();

            popup.css({
                top: (rect.top - pHeight - 12) + 'px',
                left: (rect.left - (pWidth - this.clientWidth) / 2) + 'px'
            });

            btnCancel.bind('click', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    cancelCallback(scope);
                    popup.remove();
                });
            });

            btnConfirm.bind('click', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    okCallback(scope);
                    popup.remove();
                });
            });

            scope.$apply();
        });
    }
};

return definition;
});
```